# map a list of dataframes to a coxph function to generate forest plots for each dataframe

Tags: r, purrr, survival-analysis

I would like to map a list of dataframes (`data1, data2, data3` etc) over a coxph function that runs over all variables in the dataframe, then generates a forest plot for variables with p<0.1.
My current solution uses `survivalAnalysis` package but i would like help to further map a list of dataframes to this function. Alternatively is there a way to do this with example 2 shown below (using map/reformulate) to plot the lists of coxph objects or dataframes by `ggforest`?

[data1.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18BQa47IDrWy2LiUBBM5H6w-dtaGwJ51j/view?usp=sharing)

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, ,survival,janitor,survminer,survivalAnalysis,survMisc,rlist)
data1<- read_csv('data1.csv')
data2<- read_csv(...)
data3<- read_csv(...)

colnames(data1)
cts <- c("b_cells", 
         "cd4", "cd4_tfh", "cd8_cells", "cytotoxic_cd8", "d_cs", "exhausted_cd8", 
         "granulocytes", "m1_mac", "m2_mac", "proliferating_tumour", "stroma", 
         "treg", "tumour", "unidentified", "vessels")
```

survivalAnalysis package Example

```
  map(cts, function(uni)
  {
    analyse_multivariate(data1,
                         vars('followup', 'status'),
                         covariates = list(uni),
                         covariate_name_dict = cts)
  }) %>%  list.filter(summaryAsFrame$p <0.08) %>%
    forest_plot(factor_labeller = identity,
                endpoint_labeller = c(time= "Followup"),
                log_scale = TRUE,
                p_lessthan_cutoff = 0.001,
                orderer = ~order(p), relative_widths = c(0.5, 1, 1),
                labels_displayed = c("factor"),
                label_headers = c(factor= "Cell_Type"),
                values_displayed = c("HR", "CI", "p"),
                value_headers = c(HR = "HR", CI = "95% CI", p = "p Value"),
                ggtheme = ggplot2::theme_bw(base_size = 8),
                title = "data1 Univariate Cox PH")
  ggsave('data1forest.svg')
```

Map/reformulate example

```
#map cox with reformulate
os.data1<- map(cts, ~coxph(reformulate(.x, "Surv(followup, status)"), data= data1))%>% ggforest

#dataframe to ggforest?
%>%  map(broom::tidy,conf.int=T, exponentiate=T) %>% data.table::rbindlist() %>% ggforest
```

Comment: Try `map(cts, ....) %>% map(ggforest)`